# React Native change text color if prop is true or false

Tags: reactjs, styles, native, react-props

I need to use my variant prop and change the Text color with default to "dark"
I have tried two methods, with inline styles and with stylesheet, but the colors do not change...
What am i doing wrong and how to do it properly?

```
type LabelProps = {
        variant?: "dark" | "light"; // Defaults to "dark"
        label: string;
        style?: StyleProp<ViewStyle>;
    };
    
    export function Label({ variant, label, style }: LabelProps) {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text
                    // style={[styles.labelStyle, style, { color: variant ? "light" : "dark" }]}
                    style={[styles.labelStyle, style, variant ? styles.light : styles.dark]}
                      >
                    {label}
                </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        labelStyle: {
            lineWeight: "700",
        },
        light: {
            color: "#ededed",
        },
        dark: {
            color: "#ff0000",
        },
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are curently checking that the `variant` exists.Change the condition to  `variant==='dark'`

```
style={[styles.labelStyle, style, variant === 'dark' ? styles.dark : styles.light ]}
```

Comment: Still no changes to the text color

Comment: how did you using the  `Label` conponent

Comment: i understood the problem. Your solution works, It didnt work at the beginning for me because i am using not inbuilt React Native <Text> but i import Text function from text component